# The method normalize(String) is undefined for the type index_jsp

Tags: java

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<html>
<head><title>Echo JSP</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Incoming HTTP Request</h1>

<table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

<%
Enumeration eNames = request.getHeaderNames();

while (eNames.hasMoreElements()) {

    String name = (String) eNames.nextElement();

    String value = normalize(request.getHeader(name));

    %>

    <tr><td><%= name %></td><td><%= value %></td></tr>

   <%
}

%>
</table>

</body>

</html>



<%
private String normalize (String value) {
StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();

for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
   char c = value.charAt(i);

   line.append(c);

   if (c == ';') {
      line.append("<br>");

    }

}

return line.toString();
}
 %>
```

I get a compilation error `The method normalize(String) is undefined for the type index_jsp` in this line:

> String value = normalize(request.getHeader(name));

I do not know java and this is just a test page I need to run. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose your 'normalize' method within `<%! %>` tags.You are enclosing it within `<% %>` instead, which is meant for method invocation.